# Splice in function doesn't change a character as expected

Tags: javascript, for-loop, splice, array-splice

I've been working for a while on this function but i cannot figure out why even if I'm using .splice() I don't get a modified array.
I'm providing the index at which to start changing the array "i", the number of elements to remove "1" and the element to add "str[i]".

```js
function wave(str) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if ((/[a-z]/ig).test(str[i])) {
      let st = str.split("").splice(i, 1 , str[i].toUpperCase());
      result.push(st);
    }
  }
 return result;

}


console.log(wave('hello')); // expected ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"];
console.log(wave("two words")); // ["Two words", "tWo words", "twO words", "two Words", "two wOrds", "two woRds", "two worDs", "two wordS"];
```

Comment: You might want to join the split string, otherwise it will stay an array.

Comment: [There's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59843765/11299053) a bit [faster](https://jsperf.com/oiuweroiuzxfljk/1) and shorter way to achieve your goal with high-order methods, just in case...

Answer (score 7):

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns the removed item/s. You need to keep the array - and remove and add the new item.

The regular expression does not need to be wrapped with parenthesis for accessing the [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

Before pushing to array, you need to take [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for getting a single string.

```js
function wave(str) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (/[a-z]/ig.test(str[i])) {
            let st = str.split("");
            st.splice(i, 1, str[i].toUpperCase());
            result.push(st.join(''));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(wave('hello')); // expected ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"];
console.log(wave("two words")); // ["Two words", "tWo words", "twO words", "two Words", "two wOrds", "two woRds", "two worDs", "two wordS"];
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't figure out why the reason why only the deleted character was returned. And for pointing out that i don't need to wrap my expression for the regex. I've just started using them so I'm not too confident yet.

Comment: @Mugg84 : *'...why only deleted'* it's just the way `splice()` method works - it edits array in place and returns deleted portion of it only (read through the docs for comprehensive reference); *'...don't need to wrap'* - regexp is not needed here at all, moreover it drags down your code performance.